# Display different product images for categories in magento

Tags: php, magento, categories

I am developing a magento website for a company solely selling jumpers.
each jumper can have three images,

image 1: jumper with no model
image 2. male model wearing jumper
image 3: female model wearing jumper

some jumpers will have all 3 and some will have either the base image and either the male or female image

On the homepage i display the jumper images with no model.

I want to create 2 categories (male , female)

when lets say the male category page is selected, i would like to show the male images in this page.

any ideas how i would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the quickest ways I can think of to accomplish this, if you dont want to create duplicate product is:

In Admin -> Product -> Image Tab

Always select 'thumbnail' on a female pic and 'small_image' for a male (you could also create you own image type see below)

in /app/design/frontend/default/contempospace/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

```
if([category == female])
     <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(170, 174); ?>
else
     <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(170, 174); ?>
```

You could also add a new image type, one for male and female.

How to add a new image type in Magento :

Go Admin -> Catalog -> Attribute -> Manage Attribute

Then create a new attribute of 'Media Image' for 'Catalog Input Type for Store Owner'

See [How to get access to custom Image Attribute in list.phtml in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390051/how-to-get-access-to-custom-image-attribute-in-list-phtml-in-magento)